# How do I set my profile icon in LastPass?

Tags: lastpass

Whenever I log into my LastPass vault, I see a generic user icon in the top right corner next to my email address:

[image: Lastpass Profile]

I want to replace the nondescript icon with my usual avatar, but I don't see a way to change my profile picture in account settings.

Is it possible to change my LastPass profile icon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging by [this LastPass forum thread](https://forums.lastpass.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=224775&p=756325&hilit=avatar#p756325) from February 2017, as well as having personally scoured every inch of the LastPass Account Settings, I don't believe so.

I'll let you know if and when I see this feature become available.

Answer (score 6):

I will go one step further on this. I contacted LastPass support, and they confirm that it is not possible to replace the generic user icon with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a small script that injects an image of your choice.

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
  var contents = $('iframe').contents()
  var $img = contents.find('#userMenu').children('img:not(.done)')
  if ($img.length) {
    $img
      .css({'height': '38px', 'border-radius': '50%'})
      .attr('src', 'PATH TO YOUR IMAGE')
      .addClass('done')
    clearInterval(interval)
  }
}, 1000)
```

You can inject it with an extension like [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-and-javascript-inject/ckddknfdmcemedlmmebildepcmneakaa) for Chrome. You can find others like it for every browser that supports extensions.

The script is based on an interval that checks if the profile picture element exists on the page every second. When the element exists, the script hardcodes the `height` to 38px and adds a `border-radius` of 50% to make it circular (the default image is circular on a bitmap level).

The part that says `PATH TO YOUR IMAGE` has to be replaced with the path to an image that is hosted on another server, not a local file. You can copy the URL of your profile picture on StackExchange, for example. ([`https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaomO.png`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaomO.png), in case of OP)